# Checking all $_POST values for answer and printing

Tags: php, html, variables, post, output

I am creating an online grocery site where a user can enter his/her full name & address and then proceed to purchase groceries.

There are 20 grocery items to choose from - if the user wants an item, they can simply enter how many units of that item they want; this is the html code for for just 1 of the 20 items.

```
        <tr>
           <td> Milk - $3.99/carton </td>
           <td> <input type="number" name="amtMilk" min=0> </td>
        </tr>
```

At the bottom of the page there is a submit button which leads to a confirmation page in **php**. The confirmation page outputs the users name, address, all the items ordered and a total before and after tax.

I have written out the PHP for this however, it doesn't seem to be working correctly. Below is my code shortened to 4 items:

```
<?php
   <h2> Customer Details: </h2>
   <p>Customer Name: </p> echo $_POST['Name'];
   <p>Address: </p> echo $_POST['Address'];
   $total = 0;
   <p>You ordered: </p>
   $POSTvalues = array('amtMilk', 'amtEggs', 'amtBread', 'amtCereal');
   foreach($POSTvalues as $key) {
      if ($_POST['amtMilk'] > 0) {
         $total+= 3.99*($_POST['amtMilk']);
         echo "Milk";
      }
      elseif ($_POST['amtEggs'] > 0 ) {
         $total+= 2.99*($_POST['amtEggs']);
         echo "Eggs";
      }
      elseif ($_POST['amtBread'] > 0 ) {
         $total+= 1.50*($_POST['amtBread']);
         echo "Bread";
      }
      elseif ($_POST['amtCereal'] > 0 ) {
         $total+= 4.99*($_POST['amtCereal']);
         echo "Cereal";
      }
   }
   echo "Your total before Tax is: $total"; <br>
   $afterTax = $total*0.13 + $total
   $afterDelivery = $afterTax + 3.50
   echo "Your total after tax is: $afterTax"; <br>
   echo "Your total after delivery is: $afterDelivery";<br>

   <h3> GRAND TOTAL: </h3> echo "$afterDelivery"; 

?>
```

Can anyone point out what i'm doing wrong or how I can fix this so get the desired output?

Comment: what exactly doesn't work in your code what happens when you run it

Comment: from the start: might want to use isSet() instead $_POST['key'] > 0 other than that, what are the issues? what errors do u get?

Comment: @techedryan  I get a server 500 error ; I tried adding the whole error checking thing but not sure exactly where to put it

Comment: @AndriyLysak I don't really know how to get PHP to tell me what the errors are

Comment: did you connect to the database in this file that your code is in. If not then that is probably why it is not working

Comment: error 500 means most likely there is a semantic error in PHP. look in /var/log for logs, then tail the error log and see what the error is http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38978/where-are-apache-file-access-logs-stored

Comment: A server 500 error usually means an htaccess or apache config issue/glitch, not always, but usually. Also, as others noted, you want to also test to make sure the variable is set with isset($_POST['your variable']) as well as testing the value of that post variable. Most PHP specific errors spit out the error on the page, ie, the request succeeds, but the php processor shows error.

Comment: @Lizardx trying out your isset theory -- > if isset($_POST['amtMilk'] > 0 { ....... } - does this look correct to you?

Comment: try what Mubin posted

Comment: Yes, you want to get used to reading documentation, it's part of learning how to program. php.net is excellent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're doing many things wrong.

so, how are you trying to display `html` inside `php` without using `print/echo`?

So here's revised code, hope this will resolve your issues.

```
<?php
echo '<h2> Customer Details: </h2>';
echo '<p>Customer Name: </p>'. $_POST['Name'];
echo '<p>Address: </p>'. $_POST['Address'];
$total = 0;
echo '<p>You ordered: </p>';
$POSTvalues = array('amtMilk', 'amtEggs', 'amtBread', 'amtCereal');
//foreach($POSTvalues as $key)
 {
    if (isset($_POST['amtMilk']) && $_POST['amtMilk'] > 0) {
        $total+= 3.99*($_POST['amtMilk']);
        echo "Milk";
    }
    if (isset($_POST['amtEggs']) && $_POST['amtEggs'] > 0) {
        $total+= 2.99*($_POST['amtEggs']);
        echo "Eggs";
    }
    if (isset($_POST['amtBread']) && $_POST['amtBread'] > 0) {
        $total+= 1.50*($_POST['amtBread']);
        echo "Bread";
    }
    if (isset($_POST['amtCereal']) && $_POST['amtCereal'] > 0 ) {
        $total+= 4.99*($_POST['amtCereal']);
        echo "Cereal";
    }
}
echo "Your total before Tax is: $total<br />";
$afterTax = $total*0.13 + $total; 
$afterDelivery = $afterTax + 3.50;
echo "Your total after tax is: $afterTax<br />";
echo "Your total after delivery is: $afterDelivery<br />";

echo "<h3> GRAND TOTAL: </h3>$afterDelivery"; 

?>
```

**EDIT**

Comment out the `foreach($POSTvalues as $key)` and change all `elseif` to `if`.

add another condition in `if` statement like this `&& $_POST['amtCereal'] > 0` to ensure that it has value greater than `0`

Comment: All seems to be working however the only issue is when printing the items ordered - Milk just lists 20 times instead of actual items ordered

Comment: what are you inputting and what are you expecting output?

Comment: this ain't displaying anything on confirmation page bud.

Comment: please try again - sorry was playing around with other answers -- also the total cost seems to be completely off

Comment: you're messing somewhere else, can you please post your full file on pastebin and share link please, so that I could view where you're getting error(s)

Comment: works now, however it now lists every grocery item instead of ones with a quantity grater than 0

Comment: update my post again, check now, should work like butter :)

Answer (score 2):

There is no need for the *foreach* loop, and thus no need for the *$POSTvalues* array.

Use **independent** *if* statements without the *elseif*.

A little psuedocode...

```
if (value1 > 0 )
{
  add to total
  print item
}

if (value2 > 0 )
{
  add to total
  print item
}

if (value3 > 0 )
{
  add to total
  print item
}

if (value4 > 0 )
{
  add to total
  print item
}
```

Comment: Mubin's answer does not fix the logic error. Cereal will never process unless Milk, Bread, and Eggs are not set.

Answer (score 2):

Fun fact: PHP turns elements with `name`s structured like arrays into PHP arrays.

So, you can do this:

```
<?php
$array = array(
    "milk" => array(
        "price" => 3.99,
        "unit"  => "carton",
    ),
    "eggs" => array(
        "price" => 2.99,
        "unit"  => "dozen",
    ),
);
if (isset($_POST['amt'])) {
    var_dump($_POST['amt']);
    $total = 0;
    foreach ($_POST['amt'] as $name=>$num) {
        if($num > 0) {
            $price = $array[$name]['price'];
            $amt = $_POST['amt'];
            $total += $price * $num;
            echo $num . " " . ucfirst($name) . ", ";

        }
    }

    echo "<br />Your total before Tax is: $total<br />";
    $afterTax = $total*0.13 + $total; 
    $afterDelivery = $afterTax + 3.50;
    echo "Your total after tax is: $afterTax<br />";
    echo "Your total after delivery is: $afterDelivery<br />";
    echo '<form method="POST"><button type="submit">Back</button></form>';
} else {
?><form method="POST"><table><?php
    foreach ($array as $name=>$item) {

        ?>
        <tr>
           <td> <?php echo ucfirst($name); ?> - $<?php echo $item['price']; ?>/<?php echo $item['unit']; ?> </td>
           <td> <input type="number" name="amt[<?php echo $name; ?>]" min=0> </td>
        </tr><?php
    }
?></table><input type="submit"></form><?php
}
```

I would consider either passing your price as a hidden field (for example, with the name `price[milk]`), or ensuring your array is available after you've submitted the form like I have done above. That way you don't have to hard-code in prices. The way you have it, it's going to be a nightmare to change if the prices change!

To add a new item, all you need to do is add a new key/array pair to the `$array`. No additional coding on the back-end. Just results.

Check it out [here](https://testbed-smcjones.c9users.io/easy-form.php).

Comment: Do the two code snippets go together? Im trying to compare all the answers

Comment: also - we can assume prices never change

Comment: I hate making assumptions in code... Especially when it's just as easy, or easier, to not make assumptions. It always tends to bite me. Yes, use the code together. The first snippet should be inside a `<form>` tag.

Comment: I edited. I would encourage you to only make those assumptions with great care. As an example, it may be true. In real life, it would never be true, so coding for the closest thing to real life is what I always try to do, unless it's much quicker to code for the most common use case (sometimes it definitely is... This is not one of those times).